# making jQuery .show() AND .hide() run side by side with UI effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slide

I'm trying to make a nice menu with sliding effects in jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/rXjMV/5/

```
$(".goBack").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
    });
    $("#parentSidebar").show('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    });
});
$(".sidebarMover").click(function() {
    var newmenu = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).parent().hide('slide', {
        direction: 'left'
    });
    $("#" + newmenu + "Sidebar").show('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
    });
});
```

notice that if you click on football the menu slides left and the other comes from the right but they come one below the other instead of side by side..

Tried many things, display: inline and using delay() with jQuery queue, but the problam is CSS I think, nut jQuery... any ideas?

Comment: this is because div takes width 100% , you have to think now about width and float left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
       position: absolute; width: 100%;
in the container like that:

```
<div id="sideBar">
    <div id="sideHead">TICKET MENU</div>
    <hr id="sideHeadSeperator">
       <div class="sideItemContainer" id="parentSidebar" style="position:absolute;width:100%; ">
          <div class="sideItem sidebarMover" name="football">Football<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem sidebarMover" name="tennis">Tennis<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Rugby<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Basketball<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
       </div>
       <div class="sideItemContainer" id="footballSidebar" style="display: none;position:absolute; ;width:100%;" >
          <div class="sideItem">Arsenal<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Chelsea<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Liverpool<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Manchester Utd<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="sideItem">Manchester City<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
          <div class="goBack"><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-inverse"></i> go back</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sideItemContainer" id="tennisSidebar" style="display: none;">
           <div class="sideItem">Wimbledon<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
           <div class="sideItem">Rome Masters<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
           <div class="sideItem">US Open<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
           <div class="sideItem">Roland Garros<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
           <div class="sideItem">Madrid Masters<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
           <div class="goBack"><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-inverse"></i> go back</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK amazing, that works great, BUT: the div below it is now overlaying this menu, any idea?

Comment: If subjects is resolved, put 1 and indicate that the subject is resolved on this answer. I do not quite understand your new question.